# How to use Django with Apache?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, apache2.4, django-1.10

Can someone help me and say whats wrong?

I need to use `Django + Apache`.

When I try to start Apache it shows me error: `The requested operation has failed.`

I tried to change `Listen 80` to different values but it didnt help. Also this error appears after adding next settings to `httpd.conf` file (without these settings Apache start fine):

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I use:

1) Apache 2.4 (x64)

2) Python 3.5.2 (x64)

3) Django 1.10.5

4) mod_wsgi‑4.5.15+ap24vc14‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

5) Windows 8.1 (x64)

Maybe I use wrong `mod_wsgi`? I take `mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd` file from `mod_wsgi‑4.5.15+ap24vc14‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl` archive and rename that file to `mod_wsgi.so`. After that put that file to modules folder of Apache.

**error.log** file looks like this:

```
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:30.381146 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:30.381146 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00456: Server built: May 11 2012 20:42:30
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:30.381146 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/Apache2.4 -f C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\conf\\httpd.conf -d C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\.'
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:30.381146 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 13624
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:30.646739 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13624:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:40.736467 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:42.759516 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13624:tid 328] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:42.775140 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11892:tid 692] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:51.755536 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:51.756537 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00456: Server built: May 11 2012 20:42:30
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:51.756537 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/Apache2.4 -f C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\conf\\httpd.conf -d C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\.'
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:51.757538 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8692
[Wed Jun 14 21:42:51.973446 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8692:tid 636] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 14 21:59:11.710766 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jun 14 21:59:13.712698 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8692:tid 636] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jun 14 21:59:13.731009 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 696] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:16.868389 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:16.869389 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00456: Server built: May 11 2012 20:42:30
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:16.869389 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/Apache2.4 -f C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\conf\\httpd.conf -d C:\\Program Files\\Apache2.4\\.'
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:16.870391 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7152
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:17.107601 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7152:tid 616] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:24.939591 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:26.941397 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7152:tid 616] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jun 14 23:12:26.960081 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7988:tid 692] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/RMS')
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS')

os.environ.setdefault["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "RMS.settings"

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandlers()
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    WSGIScriptAlias /rms 'C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/RMS/wsgi.py'
    Alias /media/ 'C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/media'
    Alias /media/ 'C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/media'

    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/static">
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/htdocs/RMS/media">
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**:

```
Listen 8080
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Can you include your conf file and wsgi file contents?

Comment: Hello! I update my post with all setting which I did. I need to say that `httpd.conf` file is too big. I add only that parts which I edited. What can you say? Maybe I use wrong `mod_wsgi` file?

Comment: I use `mod_wsgi` from this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi Can you advice something for me?

Comment: In error.log file I notice this: `httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 171 of C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache2.4/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.` It seems to my problem with mod_wsgi which I load.

Comment: `mod_wsgi‑4.5.15+ap24vc14‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl` -> take `mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd` file from arhive ->rename file to `mog_wsgi.so` -> put file to `modules folder` of Apache. Where I did mistake how do you think?

Comment: Whose Apache distro are you using? Only recommend install for Windows is to use ApacheLounge distro and then use ``pip install mod_wsgi`` installation method, followed by running ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to display the configuration you need to add to Apache configuration to load mod_wsgi module. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: I used `apache_2.4.2-x64-no-ssl.msi` file from there offical site which install apache 64x for my Windows 8.1 (x64). Is it not correct?

Answer (score 0):

The method [Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) mentions is the way that worked for me, I was lucky enough to come across this item: [modwgsi Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/OTb_gN8kX7w) again by Graham.

1. Install `mod_wsgi` using pip (preferably into a virtualenv)
2. Run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to get the settings to copy into your `httpd.conf` file, I chose to copy these above the LoadModules list.

Don't look to move and rename the `.pyd` file, leave it alone. To test, create a helloworld.wsgi with the following content:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
status = '200 OK'
output = b'Hello World!'

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)

return [output]
```

In your VirtualHost, create a WSGIScriptAlias pointing to the wsgi file created, e.g. `WSGIScriptAlias /test C:/wsgitest/helloworld.wsgi`